# How to show a lot of items on map?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I have a list of addresses (more 10 000 items).
I need to show all it on google map component in my android application.
For showing items on map I'm using ItemizedOverlay class.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
  mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay1);
}
```

Problem 1:
This method working slowly. Maybe I need to add items dinamically. But how?

Problem2:
I have only text addreses, no item coordinates. I try get coordinates for all items through google map api (but here are limits!).
Without coordinates I can't add items on map.

Thanks.

Comment: Clustering should optimize your performance: https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/

Comment: @AlexanderScholz user1367713 seems to be using old API and Android Maps Extensions is for v2, so this might not be a good suggestion.